# Posting additional data with Dropzone and params

Tags: javascript, dropzone

I am using Dropzone and the bootstrap example to upload files. I want to also POST additional data. I have tried a number of variations after reading the answers to other questions but I can't quite get the syntax right to get the data from the input statement as I am not very experienced with javascript.

I have two fields

```html
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
```

and I have tried to add params

```js
params: {
  firstname: ?????,
  lastname: ?????,
},
```

I know that the method works as if I use

```js
params: {
  firstname: "abcde",
  lastname: "vwxyz",
},
```

then abcde and vwxyz are posted. I just can't get the data from the input statements to POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is divided to 2.

1. How to get the values of the inputs.
2. How to pass params to *Dropzone*.

The answers:

1. Using `document.querySelector` and `.value` (See this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript#:%7E:text=in%20your%20page.-,Method%205%3A,-Use%20the%20powerful)).
2. Since the inputs are empty when you initlize *Dropzone*, `params` should be a function that retrieve the values when you need them (e.g. click `start`).

```js
params: () => ({
  firstname: document.querySelector('#firstname').value,
  lastname: document.querySelector('#lastname').value,
}),
```

https://jsbin.com/neteker/edit?js,output

More info about [`params`](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-params)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. It only works if I enter a value attribute to the input field such as <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="mnopq">. It then posts the value rather than the user input. I had looked at the answer you suggested but encountered the same problem.

Comment: Odd. Can you add a working example to your question using the snippet tool or external tools such as jsbin.com, codepen etc.?

Comment: I have uploaded my files to both  jsbin.com/kecudil/ and codepen.io/lmb21/pen/mdmOZvG. The upload.php should receive the files and posted firstname and lastname, and the session variables appid and schid and send them all to a mysql database with one record per file. All works well except for the firstname and lastname. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: A bit late but I've updated my answer and included example.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It is now working.